# deploying an ML model on gcloud with numpy c-extensions failed

Tags: python, numpy, deployment, virtualenv, gcloud

I am trying to deploy a simple Machine Learning model online, so that others can access it online easily. I have tried to to deploy it locally on LocalHost, and it works well. So now, i am trying to deploy it as a web application by using gcloud.

I successfully followed this
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-web-application-using-flask-and-deploy-it-to-the-cloud-3551c985e492/ , though it is not a ML model.

this is a view on my project directory ! (please click to view)(https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AvbZ4ERRsiS19exGPgOm8LfVjk_GWjM8)

i am using a Mac, so my python is 2.7, but as i am using Jupyter Notebook, i am on python 3.7 too. I develop my stuff mostly on Notebook through Anaconda.

This is the main.py:

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():

    int_features = [int(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    final_features = [np.array(int_features)]
    prediction = model.predict(final_features)

    output = round(prediction[0], 2)

    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='The Forecast is  {}'.format(output))

@app.route('/results',methods=['POST'])
def results():

    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    prediction = model.predict([np.array(list(data.values()))])

    output = prediction[0]
    return jsonify(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my app.yml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
  - name: ssl
    version: latest
```

My appengine_conengine.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
```

This is my requirement.txt

```
Flask
Werkzeug
numpy
sklearn
```

Then i run this:

```
pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt
```

to put the 4 required libraries in a folder named "lib". I do this because when i test run the main.py in Virtualenv, it needs Flask, numpy, and sklearn to successfully deploy on Localhost:5000.

However, when i run:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

to upload and deploy my project to gcloud, it says error like this:

```
1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/base/data/home/apps/n~sales-forecast-3mv3/20191110t154452.422348864415547477/lib/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/base/data/home/apps/n~sales-forecast-3mv3/20191110t154452.422348864415547477/lib/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python2.7 from "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/79cfdbb680326abd/python27/python27_dist/python",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.17.3" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
```

Would anyone please help? thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify in your app.yaml the numpy library as followed:

app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: static
  - url: /.*
    script: main.app

libraries:
  - name: ssl
    version: latest
  - name: numpy
    version: "1.6.1"
```

Comment: If you installed Anaconda with Python 3.7, run this command:

    -  conda install scikit-learn

Comment: If you'r using Command Shell:

Try to add scipy in your requirements.txt, 

Install:  pip install sklearn

Comment: Try to run pip3.7 install -t lib -r requirements.txt . 

Let me know if it works , if not I'll look further to help you

Comment: Can you add the error that's giving you and the lines you think what are causing the issue? Thank you

Comment: I saw the message.txt file, we can try several things in order to find what is the  issue, first of all , please run the following commands:

pip uninstall sklearn,
pip uninstall scikit-learn,
pip install sklearn.

Comment: If it doesn't work, let me know and I'll look further :)

Comment: all problem is solved, finally, thank you @Nibrass!